# Cards are drawn from a deck of 52 cards with replacements. In how many ways can 10 cards be drawn so that the 10th card is the first repetition?

Tags: combinatorics

Sorry(for as there are similar questions but not the exact question),I tried to find it out the solution of this question, I searched it on everywhere but I didn't get the solution, It is the question taken from C.L.LIU Book ANd I don't know the answer.
My Approach is like
First card could be taken out 52C1 ways.
Second card has 51 ways (even though with replacement 52 - 1 (card which is already taken out) = 51).
Similarly, Third card has 50 ways.
Fourth - 49 ways.
Fifth - 48 ways
Sixth - 47 ways
Seventh - 46 ways
Eighth - 45 ways
Ninth - 44 ways

All the above should be multiplied.
Now above multiplication has also counted 9! arrangements which should be divided.

The tenth card should be repetition of one of the nine cards ... So tenth card has 9 ways to be taken out.

(52×51×50×49×48×47×46×45×44×9)/9!

Is this answer Correct?If not then please tell me the solution it will be very helpful.

Comment: There aren't 51 options on the second draw because there cannot be repeats until the 10th card is drawn. There would be 48.

Comment: @Jeremy I think the OP means that a repeat is the same card -- both rank and suit.

Comment: @saulspatz A 52 card deck does not have any repeating cards.

Comment: I agree with everything but the division by $9!$.  There's no reason for this.

Comment: @Jeremy the OP mentions "with replacement". Once you replace cards, it has duplicates.

Comment: See also [a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3323948), where there could be repetitions before the 10th card.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. There are $_{52}P_9$ ways to choose the first nine cards because order matters. There are $9$ ways to choose the final card. I am not sure why you are dividing by $9!$, though.

Comment: Division by $9!$ would mean that order does not matter.

Comment: Ok Thank you but i was consider that suppose A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I are selected,Then the order in which they are selected BACDEIGH, etc. are there so total 9! are there so i was dividing it with that only